# Valuar inicio de una linea C++

Tags: c++, c, archivo

Tengo que hacer un proyecto, y para ello necesito leer linea por linea un archivo tal que;

```
/+ para el curso de Lenguajes Formales y Autómatas
/+ Este autómata reconoce una cadenas palíndromas de símbolos a’s y b’s y una c al
/+ centro de la cadena
S = {q0.q1,q2}
S0 = {q0}
A = {a,b,c}
AC = {Z0}
T = {q2}
Z0 = {Z0}
q0 a Z0 (a,Z0,q0)
q0 a a (a,a,q0)
q0 c Z0 ($,Z0,q1)
q0 c a (a,Z0,q1)
q1 b a ($,$,q1)
q1 $ Z0 ($,Z0,q2)
```

Quiero que, por ejemplo, lea la primera linea y que si encuentra un "/+" marque toda esa linea como un comentario y me la muestre. O, que si ve una "S" seguida de un "=" me muestre lo que va después del "=". Agradecería mucho su ayuda, me he estado comiendo la cabeza en como hacerlo y no lo consigo.

Tengo este código pero no lee la primera linea y asume que las demás son todas comentarios.

```
while (getline(Archivo, Linea)) {

        cursor = strdup(Linea.c_str());


        if (cursor="/+"){
            getline(Archivo, Linea);
            cout<<"Este es un comentario"<<Linea;
        }

 }
```